# complex operation using stream api in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement, where I have a string which is comma separated and then I need to read the individual value and create a collection of object using them.

For example my string contains value like `foo , bar, baz` and then I need to create three object using them like

```
Object foo = new Object("foo");
Object bar = new Object("bar");
Object baz = new Object("baz");
```

**There might be multiple spaces before and after the `,`, so I want to remove them as well, so that my object is created with proper string**, how can I do this using stream API and single line of code?

Comment: you can't create variables at runtime, use an Array or List;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I denoted your class as `YourClass`, since `Object` is already taken.

You can use `split` to split the input `String` into tokens, and `trim` to eliminate the spaces:

```
List<YourClass> list =
    Arrays.stream(inputStr.split(","))
          .map(s -> new YourClass(s.trim())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: if doing streams: `...split(",")).map(String::trim).map(YourClass::new).collect(...` or  `...split("\\s*,\\s*)).map(YourCalss::new).collect(...`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger didn't get you

Comment: @user7851946 he meant that you can split with the suggested reg expression to eliminate the leading and trailing spaces instead of calling `trim` later.

Comment: Thanks @Eran, you were super fast, one more thing why you said, `object` is already taken, I mentioned it just for example purpose

Comment: @user7851946 Object is an actual class (and an important one - the super class of all classes in Java). You shouldn't use that name to represent some other class, since that may be confusing

Comment: or use `map` to call `trim` - more function oriented IMO (just style)

Comment: I’d rather use `inputStr.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*")` instead of having to invoke `trim()` on every created sub-string. Alternatively, `Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*").splitAsStream(inputStr.trim()) .map(YourClass::new) .collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger using `\s*,\s*` as splitting pattern will eliminate white-space arount the commas, but you might need to call `trim()` on the input string first, if there can be leading or trailing white-space (where no comma appears).

Comment: @Eran , instead of having a list of my objects, how can I get a array of objects? as I need to pass these to third party method which doesn't accept a list

Comment: @user7851946 instead of collect use `toArray(YourClass[]::new)`